# Row pattern Sum of digits

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns, numbers

How to print the following pattern?
If row and column are given.
For example

```
x=5
y=6
```

starting from x and the next row is the sum value of the previous row.

```
55555
5+5+5+5+5=25
```

then the next row must be

```
25252

output:
55555
25252
16161
15151
13131
99999
```

Can anyone help me to write a program to solve this question?

Comment: Did you try anything? Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I'm a learner. I clearly have no idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this.

```
def f(x, y):
    orig_x = x
    for _ in range(y):
        tmp = (str(x)*orig_x)[:orig_x]
        x = sum([int(i) for i in tmp])
        print(tmp)

f(5,6)

55555
25252
16161
15151
13131
99999
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient code but..

```
#get the total given the initial number/row
def getSum(number):
    total = 0
    for num in number:
        total += int(num)
    return total

#print the row given the number and the number of columns
def printRow(number, columns):
    counter = 0
    row = ""
    while (counter < columns):
        for num in number:
            row += num
            counter += 1
            if (counter >= columns):
                break
    print(row)
    return row

x = 5 #initial number
y = 6 #number of rows

m = x

for z in range(y):
    n = getSum(str(x))
    x = printRow(str(n), m)
```

Answer (score 0):

## The same Pattern prob using Java

### Add your own addDigits() method

```
public static void pattern(int N, int K) {
    var originalN = N;
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        String temp = new String(new char[originalN]).replace("\0", Integer.toString(N));
        String newTemp = temp.substring(0, originalN);
        System.out.println(newTemp);
        N = addDigits(newTemp);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    int K = sc.nextInt();
    pattern(N, K);
}
```